# Excel VBA Convert Milliseconds to Floored Days Without Overflow Error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert milliseconds to floored days in Excel and am getting overflow errors no matter what I try.

Here are the methods I've tried.

```
Public Function Floor(ByVal myValue As Variant) As Variant
    Floor = Int(myValue) - 1 * (Int(myValue) > myValue)
End Function
Sub Test()
    Dim MilSecs As Variant: MilSecs = 321049000
    Dim Seconds As Variant: Seconds = MilSecs / 1000
    Dim Days As Variant: Days = Floor(Seconds / (60 * 60 * 24)) 'Produces overflow error (should be 3)
    Dim Days As Variant: Days = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(60 * 60 * 24, 1) 'Produces overflow error (should be 3)
    Debug.Print 60 * 60 * 24 'Produces overflow error (should be 86,400)
    Debug.Print "MilSecs: " & MilSecs & ", Seconds: " & Seconds & ", Days: " & Days
End Sub
```

As you can see from the first Debug.Print line, Excel seems to be crashing while computing the 60 * 60 * 24 that is needed for my formula, before even getting to any data type concerns... What gives? Excel VBA must be able to handle math as simple as this, so what am I missing? Please assist, thanks!

Comment: Changing `60 * 60 * 24` for `86400` seems to fix the problem. Changing the numbers for variables with those exact same values also works. Why it is a problem, I do not know.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I've already done that myself but, since I view that as duct tape & it makes the code less intuitive and more magic-numbery, I was hoping to get a polished solution from the experts.

Comment: Not as magic numbery as you think. 86400 is known to be the total second in a day.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not known by me, and I like to write my code so that even people who don't know these "known" numbers can read the code effortlessly. Like myself when I revisit the code a few months later, lol. Hence, I'm trying to figure out how to compute this seemingly issueless calculation of 60 * 60 * 2. This should help me to both A) compute other similar calculations without resorting to magic numbers and B) understand how to write less problematic code in VBA. This could be a very helpful lesson for me... Thanks!

Comment: Looks like that expression is evaluated to some data type for which the result is too big. [Reference](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-vba-expression-evaluation-returns-unexpected/ab30e353-885c-4036-b7f0-fa90a325df7d).

Comment: `Const SECS_PER_DAY As Long = 86400 `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can denote the numbers as `Double` by appending `#` onto them. `Double` has a larger range and wont overflow.

E.g. `60# * 60 * 24` you only need to add `#` onto the first number because VBA will automatically convert the other ones as it does the operations.

```vb
Public Function Floor(ByVal myValue As Variant) As Variant
    Floor = Int(myValue) - 1 * (Int(myValue) > myValue)
End Function
Sub Test()
    Dim MilSecs As Variant: MilSecs = 321049000
    Dim Seconds As Variant: Seconds = MilSecs / 1000
    Dim Days As Variant: Days = Floor(Seconds / (60# * 60 * 24)) 'Produces overflow error (should be 3)
    Dim Days2 As Variant: Days2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(60# * 60 * 24, 1) 'Produces overflow error (should be 3)
    Debug.Print 60# * 60 * 24 'Produces overflow error (should be 86,400)
    Debug.Print "MilSecs: " & MilSecs & ", Seconds: " & Seconds & ", Days: " & Days
End Sub
```

Side note, you should type your functions and variables, it helps VBA to automatically convert values to the correct types. `Dim Seconds As Double`

Comment: Thanks Toddleson! That works. I didn't know about type declaration shorthand characters or being able to do that inline in a calculation, cool!